# How to access YCbCr color attributes in Go

Tags: go

I'm iterating over an image's pixels trying to get the individual color values and average them out. When I do this:

```
bounds := img.Bounds()

for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
  for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(img.At(x, y)))     
  }
}
```

I get `color.YCbCr` a billion times. If I print it without `reflect.TypeOf`, I get a result like this:

```
{154 135 124}   
{153 135 124}   
{152 135 124}   
{152 135 124}   
{151 135 124}   
{149 135 124}   
{147 135 124}
```

I need to be able to access the individual Y, Cb and Cr colors, but when I try `img.At(x, y).Cb` or `img.At(x, y)['Y']` or even `img.At(x, y)[0]`, I get various compile-time errors telling me that `color.Color` doesn't have those methods or doesn't support indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this for future reference, but to access the underling `color.YCbCr` you just need to type assert the value, example:

```
for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
    for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {
        if c, ok := img.At(x, y).(color.YCbCr); ok {
            fmt.Println(c.Y, c.Cb, c.Cr)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(img.At(x, y)))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the method I needed was `img.At(x, y).RGBA()`, this returns those values respectively.

Comment: besides: using reflect in (the) loop will dramatically drop performance. From "laws of reflection" (http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection):  ''It's a powerful tool that should be used with care and avoided unless strictly necessary.''

Comment: I was only using reflect to try and figure out what variable type I was working with, that obviously wouldn't have been left in production code.

Comment: Don't think that is true. When calling `.RGBA()` you are calling into struct `color YCbCr` method RGBA() which does a conversion from YCbCr to RGBA, losing some detail as compared to casting to color.YCbCr and getting the luminance value Y.